# No Suitable driver exception when I try to connect to postgres using the jdbc step in SoapUI (free version)

Tags: postgresql, soapui

I am sorry this question was asked many times.
Steps that I followed are as follows

1. downloaded the postgres jdbc driver from the following link
   https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
   downloaded the latest version
2. Pasted the jar file in the soapui_home/bin/ext folder
3. Restarted SoapUI still getting the same error
   [image]

4. I have added a jdbc step in SoapUI
5. Here is the driver, I have used PostgreSQL/org.postgresql.Driver
6. The string is dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databaseName?user=username&password=password

Environment
Redhat Linux
jdk version is 11
SoapUI version 5.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the driver string in the jdbc  step to org.postgresql.Driver. It started working.